# GET Request Error (Connection Reset) with Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

So I'm making a simple notes app using Entity Framework with ASP.Net Core for my backend and AngularJS for frontend.

The expected behaviour is that when the app initiates, it should load a list of notes that are already saved in my database (MySQL)

Thing is, when my app does the Get request it rertuns the following error:
[image]

Before this I had a problem with CORS that I solved by adding `http://` to my connection string and after solving that, I got this. I've been looking all over the internet but I don't seem to find an answer.

This is my `note.service.ts`

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Note } from '../note';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NoteService {

  private url: string = "http://localhost:44353/api/NotesLists";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getNotes(): Observable<Note[]> {
    return this.http.get<Note[]>(this.url);
  }
}
```

This is my home component (where I subscrirbe to get the response):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NoteService } from '../services/note.service';
import { Note } from '../note';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public notes: Note[] = [];
  
  constructor(private noteService: NoteService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.noteService.getNotes()
        .subscribe(data => this.notes = data);
  }

}
```

And my `[HttpGet]` request on .Net Core

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = _datacontext.NotesList
                                        .Include(notesList => notesList.Note)
                                        .ToList();

            if (response.Count == 0)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

And my `DataContext` for better context (Ha!)

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using noteAppAPI.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace noteAppAPI.Helpers
{
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> option) : base(option)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<NotesList> NotesList { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    
}
}
```

Comment: Angular code seems ok. Have you tried to call the API from postman or directly from browser (since it's a GET, you can do it if don't need particular headers when making the call)?

Comment: Just open the browser and try to reach your API URL : http://localhost:44353/api/NotesLists

Comment: I've tried but I get the same error, just with Chrome's message lol @devj, is thee anything I can do or check from there? Postman also gives Connection reset error

Comment: i assume you have tested your _datacontext.NotesList works, put a breakpoint on there and ensure you are even getting there, and examine visual studio output see if anything in there

Comment: @MarkHomer Breakpoints don't seem to trigger at all, could this mean my api isn't even getting the get request?

Comment: @JesusCastañeda would seem so, you should be using HTTPS, and enable CORS on the API just allow any origin

Comment: @MarkHomer Do you mean to add https:// to my connection string? Also enabling CORS was a huge problem before lol

Comment: @JesusCastañeda yeah the API is probably running as HTTPS you will need to enable CORS in it else you will get your original error for CORS failure.  you wont be able to make any requests against the API without CORS being setup even if it just to allow any origin. just refer to this on how to add it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @MarkHomer this worked wonders, thanks a lot man! I've been struggling all morning with it T-T THANK YOUUU

Comment: @JesusCastañeda no prob glad you got it working :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkHomer for his suggestion in the comments. The solution to this was:

Change connection string on `note.service.ts` from

`private url: string = "http://localhost:44353/api/NotesLists";`

to

`private url: string = "http://localhost:44353/api/NotesLists";`

This would lead me to have to enable CORS in my API so the HTTPS request would work.

To enable CORS in `Startup.cs` add in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
        services.AddCors(c =>
        {
            c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
        });
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => {
            option.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
        });
```

And also in `Configure` method in the same file:

```
        app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```